# Rails Active Record Search - Name includes a word

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

Im trying to pull all records from a Project model that includes in the project_name the word 'Fox'.  I can do an active record search and return specific project_names, like 'Brown Fox':

```
@projects = Project.where("project_name like ?", "Brown Fox")
```

But if I want to return all the names that INCLUDE 'Fox', this does not work unless the complete project name is 'Fox':

```
@projects = Project.where("project_name like ?", "Fox")
```

How do I do a search that returns all the objects with the word 'Fox' in the name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using:

```
variable = "Fox"
Project.where("project_name like ?", "%#{variable}%")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SQL `%` operator:

```
@projects = Project.where("project_name like ?", "%Fox%")
```

Note that if you want your query to return results ignoring the word case, you can use PostgreSQL `ilike` instead of `like`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) ?

With ransack you can do something like

```
@projects = Project.search(:project_name_cont => "Fox")
```

If you think it is too much for what you need. you can use the `%` operator as MurifoX said

Comment: Thanks. Im looking into Ransack now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that will allow you to handle any number of input words and to search for all of them within a name. I was looking for this answer and didn't find the more complicated case, so here it is:

```
def self.search(pattern)
  if pattern.blank?  # blank? covers both nil and empty string
    all
  else
    search_functions = []
    search_terms = pattern.split(' ').map{|word| "%#{word.downcase}%"}
    search_terms.length.times do |i|
      search_functions << 'LOWER(project_name) LIKE ?'
    end
    like_patterns = search_functions.join(' and ')
    where("#{like_patterns}", *search_terms)
  end
end
```